# How to Remove Push Notification from my iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification

my current app doesn't use push notification. however when i upload build on testflight after upload build successfully i got error on my mail.

below my error description:

**Missing Push Notification Entitlement** - Your app appears to include API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required. You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning. If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the developer for information on removing the API.

Anybody can help to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Xcode 7? I have the same problem when switching from Xcode 6 to 7.

Comment: i am using xcode 6.4

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i regenerate Distribution Provisioning Profile. but some last days my mac was not restarted. just i restart my Mac. now it's solved.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, the email your received is not an error but a warning, you can still distribute your app if you think your app isn't involved with Push Notifications.

To stop this warning, I suggest you regenerate your Distribution Provisioning Profile in Member Center, then download the new profile and add it to Xcode. Next steps are same as you archive and distribute the build. Hope it helps.

Comment: I was remove Distribution Provisioning Profile from my mac and regenerate new Distribution Provisioning Profile. i tried it. but continue getting warning.

Comment: i was do again that which you suggest but i got warning again

Comment: @bhautikmewada191 I have no idea then. But anyway, if you are urgent to upload your build, just ignore the warning.

Comment: @bhautikmewada191 Have you found any solution?

Comment: i was found solution i need to restart my mac

Comment: @bhautikmewada191 good to hear, I should also reboot my mac :)

Answer (score -1):

Please check your developer account-->AppID-->your app bundle name--> that your application has enabled Push notification services for development or not. If it is then disable it.

Comment: thanks, i was already checked push notification service was disable.

Comment: so is the problem still remaining?

Comment: In your app delegate are you setting delegate to Push notifications? or registering for push notification? 
If so delete that code.. plz check n comment

Comment: my app does not use push notification so i was not written that methods in app delegate

Comment: can u post your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method ?

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {                  
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:THEME_COLOR];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];                    
    return YES;
}